# RavenDB conflict with System.Data.Entity

Tags: ravendb

We are using Ravendb 3 in an `ASP.NET` MVC controller action. If you try to use the RavenDb async session with the `ToListAsync()` and if you also have a `ToListAsync()` on an Entity query that has nothing to do with Raven database, an error is thrown saying that `ToListAsync` can only be used with Raven or other errors such as "The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable. Is this a known issue? Are there any work arounds?

Please advise.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use it as an extension method, use the static method, instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We have the following using (IAsyncDocumentSession RavenSession = store.OpenAsyncSession())
            {
                var favs = await RavenSession.Query<FavRecent>("Favs").Where(f => f.UserId == uid).ToListAsync();
               
                return favs;
            }. Where do we call the Static Method. Thanks